# Displaying larger image size using opencv when displaying output

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

While performing template matching, the output displayed is very small in size which doesn't help in determining where the bounding box is, How can I display bigger image when displaying output?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img_rgb = cv2.imread('ddd/radiobutton.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('ddd/temp.png', 0)
height, width = template.shape[::]
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
plt.imshow(res, cmap='gray')
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = min_loc 
bottom_right = (top_left[0]+ width, top_left[1]+height)
# cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, top_left, bottom_right, (255, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, top_left, bottom_right, (255, 0, 0), 10)
cv2.imshow("Matched image", img_rgb)
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
plt.show(1900,2000)
```

Here is a screenshot that will be provide an idea about the small size of output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the figure size with the following line:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(x, y))
```

The parameters `x` and `y`need to be set, for your specific image.